# How can I use indexPath from SwipeCellKit in prepare(for: segue)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using the SwipeCellKit [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) for a project, and I want to make it so that I swipe to reveal an edit button, and then click edit to segue to another view controller.

When I click on the row, it works, passing the Auto object to the new view controller, using this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print (indexPath.row)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "editAutoDetailsSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editAutoDetailsSegue" {
        print("Preparing to segue")
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EditAutoInfoViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            print("Row Selected")
            destinationVC.selectedAuto = autombiles?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the extension that I have implemented. It works as is, but when I perform the segue, it doesn't pass the Auto object to the new view controller.

```
extension AutoViewController: SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
            // handle action by updating model with deletion
            if let theAuto = self.autombiles?[indexPath.row] {
                do {
                    try self.realm.write {
                        self.realm.delete(theAuto)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("There was an error deleting the auto \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        let editAction = SwipeAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { action, indexPath in
            // Go to Editor
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editAutoDetailsSegue", sender: self)
        }

        return [deleteAction, editAction]
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
        var options = SwipeOptions()
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
        options.transitionStyle = .border
        return options
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to access the indexPath from the swiped cell?

Comment: You need to provide the index path to your segue somehow.  You aren't selecting the row, so the `indexPathForSelectedRow` isn't set.  The simplest way is to send the index path as the `sender` - `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editAutoDetailsSegue", sender: indexPath)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tip from Paulw11 - That was only part of the solution, but it was the vital piece I was missing.

So I had to set sender: indexPath, but I also had to tell the prepare for: segue ... how to handle it.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editAutoDetailsSegue" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EditAutoInfoViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedAuto = autombiles?[indexPath.row]
        }
        if let indexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath {
            destinationVC.selectedAuto = autombiles?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
    let editAction = SwipeAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { action, indexPath in
        // Go to Editor
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editAutoDetailsSegue", sender: indexPath)
    }
```

Thanks a bunch!